# Using a Function-Like Macro to check if variable is defined

Tags: c, macros, segmentation-fault

The following macro causes a segfault when a *customer_num is NULL is passed through.

```
#define SAVE(a,b,c) if(a){stchar(a,b,c);}
```

In the macro is there a way I can check for if a is defined and if not then just use NULL.
the macro works if I just use NULL as shown below.

```
SAVE(NULL,buf,16);


1)save_cust(NULL);
2)save_cust(char **customer_number,..etc);
3)SAVE(*customer_number,buf,16); //causes seg fault since it *customer_number is undefined
```

Comment: What do you mean by "defined"?

Comment: Your compiler will spit out an error if you haven't **declared** a variable your are attempting to use. What you are doing only takes effect if `a!=0`. Is that what you mean by "defined"?

Comment: By defined I mean is it NULL. if customer_number is NULL then shouldn't *customer_number be NULL as well?

Comment: @caaruiz -Using the preprocessor directives you check if a macro is defined or not but you cant check   
if a variable has been defined or not.

Comment: `if(customer_number)SAVE(*customer_number,buf,16);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I was hoping to use the macro to check if a variable has been defined or not, but as Abhishek pointed out I can't do that with in the macro.

Comment: @caaruiz Note that a segfault occurs before the function is called  logically.

Comment: As a side note, don't define function like macros that don't behave like functions. In your case, you have a "dangling `else`" problem. The usual trick to do this is to pack all of this into `do { ... } while (0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Given this macro

```
#define SAVE(a,b,c) if(a){stchar(a,b,c);}
```

and the following invocation

```
SAVE(*customer_number,buf,16);
```

the output from the preprocessor is

```
if (*customer_number){stchar(*customer_number,buf,16);}
```

The result is that you're not checking whether `customer_number` is NULL, but instead you're checking whether `*customer_number` is NULL.  When `customer_number` is NULL, checking `*customer_number` causes a seg_fault.

One solution to the problem is to define the macro as

```
#define SAVE(a,b,c) if(a){stchar(*a,b,c);}
```

and then invoke the macro as

```
SAVE(customer_number,buf,16);
```

---

Upon further review, I think the macro you're looking for is

```
#define SAVE(a,b,c) if(a && *a){stchar(*a,b,c);}
```

If `customer_number` is in fact a pointer to a pointer, then you need to verify first that `customer_number` is not NULL, and then verify that `*customer_number` is not NULL.